# Will MS Office 2010 (PC version) work via homebrew's wine on a Mac?

Tags: ms-office, wine

The title says it all. **I want to know whether MS Office 2010 (i.e. the Windows version) can be installed via homebrew's wine on a Mac?**

I'm thinking of trying this and if I do and it works, will post method and results here.  In the meantime, any tips or warnings appreciated...

I've already used wine successfully in one instance before.

(Context, in case you wonder why I'm even attempting this: Office 2010 serves its purpose well, and legitimate licenses are available (at least in the EU according to reselling regulations) very cheaply.  Since I don't need or want the more intrusive newer versions of office, if this works, it may be a good solution. Mac office in the 2011 variant tends to behave badly in my experience - arrogant in its behaviour on the system, so if wine can offer a functional sandbox, that appeals).

Comment: Perhaps a [search of WinHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=17336) would be in order?  Is this *really* necessary as Office Online is available free of charge?

Answer (score 1):

Install to a clean wineprefix following the instructions in the https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=17336. After installing set riched20.dll to native to get around bug 14980. Do not install it with winetricks; Office installs its own version.

But I really recommend use CrossOver for Mac http://www.codeweavers.com/ use can try it for 14 days and if you like it. The license is $30. CrossOver takes care of all you need to install office 2010 on your Mac without problems. *I must say that I am not employee of Code Weavers, I am not the developer of the application. I am just happy customer from 2006.*

Regards

Comment: Incorrect info given above - license for codweavers is not $30 - currently it is $60 (or $40 without any updates).

Comment: @mwal please go to the official page and see the prices. https://www.codeweavers.com/store and be sure you click on + show more options